PnP Framework assign Permission to the SharePoint Using PowerCell
We have assign the App to the selected SharePoint Site by using PnP PowerShell and now pnp removed that support. Is there any other way we can assign permission to a particular user to access the selected SharePoint site? We have referred to the link below to assign permission using Powercell.
https://medium.com/@sanghuynh_73086/how-to-access-sharepoint-site-using-microsoft-graph-08d20311c61c#:~:text=2.2.-,1.,Sharepoint%20Site%20(selected%20site)
We are fetching the client's SharePoint documents or files using the Graph API. To do this, we have followed these steps to retrieve documents from SharePoint:
Step 1:
Open PowerShell (recommended to use version >= 7.x to run code) in local.

Step 2:
If we haven’t PnP PowerShell locally, we are use the following command to install it:
### Install PnP PowerShell in local PowerShell:

Install-Module PnP.PowerShell -Scope CurrentUser
Install-Module SharePointPnPPowerShellOnline -Scope CurrentUser

Step 3:
Connect Sharepoint Site Online:
### Connect Sharepoint Online:

$devAsiaP = "https://mydomain.sharepoint.com/sites/appname"
Connect-PnPOnline -Url $devAsiaP

Step 4:
Verify connection:
### Verify connection:

Get-PnPSite

Step 5:
Grant permission (Permissions Write) for the selected site.
### Grant permission for selected site:

Grant-PnPAzureADAppSitePermission -AppId "{client_id}" -DisplayName "{app_name}" -Permissions Write -Site https://mydomain.sharepoint.com/sites/appname

Step 6:
Granted permission successfully:

After this step, the app has permission to control the selected Sharepoint Site.
Now, the problem is PnP doesn't provide to assign the permission(below-mentioned steps). and we are looking into an alternative solution.

Can you provide more details on what you want to achieve?

Have edited the question with details

You can make use of this API https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/site-post-permissions?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#request Let me know if it works for you will post the answer with details

Sure, will try.

Let me know Will post an answer if it works:)

Which type of permission do we have to assign to the application? Currently, we have given  Site.Selected and User.Read permission only.

Site.Selected assigned at both Microsoft.Graph as well as SharePoint level

Sites.fullcontrol.all application type Microsoft Graph api permission

The concern is here, we would not want to fetch all details from the sharepoint where we need some specific permissions to get similar details which we were able to get using PnP-powershell module.

means we need to fetch for specific users files and documents, using site.fullcontrol we can access all the data from that domain. Is there any way we can restrict that?

Create two applications one to assign permissions and one more to access the files. First application requires sites.fullcontril.all and another requires sites.selected

To assign Permission to the SharePoint, you can also make use of Microsoft Graph API like below:
Create two Microsoft Entra ID applications, one to assign site permission to the application and one more the application you want to assign permission.
In the first application, grant Sites.FullControl.All application type API permission:

Grant Sites.Selected to the other application:

Now generate the access token using the first application (that is granted with  Sites.FullControl.All)  Api permission:
https://login.microsoftonline.com/TenantID/oauth2/v2.0/token

grant_type : client_credentials
client_id : ClientIDofFirstApp
client_secret : SecretofFirstApp
scope : https://graph.microsoft.com/.default


Now create the permission:
POST https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/{sitesId}/permissions
Content-Type: application/json

{
  "roles": ["write"],
  "grantedToIdentities": [{
    "application": {
      "id": "AppIDwhichyouwanttograntpermission",
      "displayName": "SharePointApp"
    }
  }]
}


Reference:
Create permission - Microsoft Graph v1.0 | Microsoft
